# Can't bind to 'dividerColor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-form-field'

Tags: angular, npm, localhost, mat-form-field

I created an Angular app and compiled it successfully:

```
 10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 163 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 399 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.09 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 186 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.95 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-11-15T07:04:24.466Z - Hash: 14ff089b7b0356766301 - Time: 16736ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:4200` I see only the name and logo of the app in my browser tab, but a blank white page in content place. I can run other apps on this address but this new app doesn't work and show any thing.

You can find the project files here: https://github.com/rajishpajish/test

EDIT: I checked the developer console as an answer suggested and found this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dividerColor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-form-field'.
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component and it has 'dividerColor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <p>
        <mat-form-field class="full-width"
         [ERROR ->]dividerColor="{{(formErrors.author) ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}">
          <input matInput formControlNa"): ng:///AppModule/DishDetailComponent.html@62:9
Can't bind to 'dividerColor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-form-field'.
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component and it has 'dividerColor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
      <p>
        <mat-form-field class="full-width"
         [ERROR ->]dividerColor="{{(formErrors.comment) ? 'warn' : 'primary'}}">
          <textarea matInput formContr"): ng:///AppModule/DishDetailComponent.html@75:9
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11188)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25721)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25709)
    at compiler.js:25653
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25653)
    at compiler.js:25566
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25565)
```

As I am a new Angular learner don't know if this module is deprecated and how to replace it with new one?

Comment: Check the console, you might have some errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the developer console, you'll see there's an error in one of the templates (DishDetailComponent.html@75:9):

[image: Error in template DishDetailComponent.html@75:9]

As you can see, it complains about there's no `dividerColor` property in the `mat-form-field` component. Perhaps it's a deprecated property because I don't see it in its API: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

Answer (score 0):

I found a changes log here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/86ta8k/angular_material_600beta5_changelog/ and replaced all `dividerColor`s with `color` in my project and it worked!

Thanks for @Fel's help.